# finding the caller object given its name only

Tags: python-3.x, code-inspection

I want to find the caller *callable* from within the called object, without explcitely forwarding the caller to the called as an object.

My current code looks something like this:

```
class Boo:

@classmethod
def foo(cls, aa, b2=2):
    _ret = aa + b2
    autolog(fn=Boo.foo, values={"input": locals(), "output": _ret}, message="This is what it should look like")
    autolog_nameless(values={"input": locals(), "output": _ret}, message="This would be convenient")
    return _ret
```

and yields

```
DEBUG | Boo.foo with aa=3.14159, b2=2 yields 5.14159. Message: This is what it should look like
DEBUG | cls=<class '__main__.Boo'>, aa=3.14159, b2=2, _ret=5.14159 yields 5.14159. Message: This would be convenient
```

The method `autolog` gets the `locals()` and the caller method `fn`, and parses them using the signature of the caller. This works nice and provides the desired output, but requires passing the caller as an object - something I'd like to avoid as I'm refractoring to include this feature and have about 1000 places to modify.

What I'd like to achieve is: pass `locals()` only; get the *name* of the caller within `autolog_nameless`, using `inspect.stack()[1][3]` or rather `inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_name` (latter has much less overhead), and using this - an possibly the information in `locals()` - find the caller *object* to inspect it for its signature.

The method autolog_nameless gets `cls`, actually the class as part of locals() (or would get self if the caller was a simple method), but I can't really do anything with it.

I'd think all the information required is given, but I just can't find a solution. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out it's quite simple: listing the methods of the class object found in `locals()` and searching by name should do the trick.

Code, without error checking:

```
# getting all methods of the class
methods = inspect.getmembers(locals()['cls'], predicate=inspect.ismethod)

# finding the callers name; won't work within the list comprehension for scope issues
_name = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_name

# methods is a list of tuples, each tuple holds the name and the method object
fn = [x for x in methods if x[0] == _name][0][1]
```

and fn is the caller object to check the signature.

Note, `locals()['cls']` works here as in the example we have a classmethod, but this is just the object that the called method belongs to.